# append value to dict from another dict in list loop

Tags: python-3.x

I struggle to append a value to a dicts from another dicts that all sits in lists (that means to iterate)
I am a beginner with python so if anyone could help me on that one :)
here an example of what I am trying to do:

```
dict_a = [ 
{ 'key1' : 'name',
  'key2' : 'int1',
  'key3' : 'useless',
  'key4' : 'valtest'},

{ 'key1' : 'name',  
  'key2' : 'int2',
  'key3' : 'useless',
  'key4' : 'valtest' }]

dict_b = [
{ 'a' : '1',
  'b' : 'name',
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : 'int0',
  'e' : 'id0' },

{ 'a' : '1',
  'b' : 'name',
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : 'int1',
  'e' : 'id1' },

{ 'a' : '1',
  'b' : 'name',
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : 'int2',
  'e' : 'id2' },

{ 'a' : '1',
  'b' : 'name',
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : 'int3',
  'e' : 'id3' },

{ 'a' : '1',
  'b' : 'name',
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : 'int1',
  'e' : 'id4' }]
```

and here is the result I would like to obtain:

```
dict_c = [ 
{ 'key1' : 'name',
  'key2' : 'int1',
  'key3' : 'useless',
  'key4' : 'valtest',
  'key5' : 'id1'},

{ 'key1' : 'name',
  'key2' : 'int2',
  'key3' : 'useless',
  'key4' : 'valtest',
  'key5' : 'id2'}]
```

Notice that 'key5' on dict_c is 'e' on dict_b based on conditions key1 = b and key2 = d

With my small knowledge I have tried this:

```
for v in dict_a and vv in dict_b:
  if v['key1'] == vv['b'] and v['key2'] == vv['d']:
    v['key5'] = vv['e']
```

but some times traceback says:
NameError: name 'vv' is not defined

And some times:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

How could I do to obtain the result ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `for v in dict_a and vv in dict_b:` is not the right way of doing what you want. What you want is a nested for-loop. Something like: `for v in dict_a: for vv in dict_b: if v['key1'] == vv['b']...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there i sligtly modify Your code:

```
for v in dict_a and vv in dict_b:
    if v['key1'] == vv['b'] and v['key2'] == vv['d']:
        v['key5'] = vv['e']
```

To

```
for v in dict_a:
    for vv in dict_b:
        if v['key1'] == vv['b'] and v['key2'] == vv['d']:
            v['key5'] = vv['e']
```

check this code in sandbox:
[python sandbox](https://repl.it/repls/CruelSugaryNamebinding#main.py)

Comment: Many thanks Jakub !! it works like a charms and I was almost giving up.